# How to save an object of model that have one to one field?

Tags: django

I want to save a comment to any posts by click on button but i receive an error:
**ValueError at /user_add_comment
save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'profile_user'.**

## model:

```
    class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        bio = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="Bio")
        profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_users', blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username


class CommentPostModel(models.Model):
    profile_user = models.OneToOneField(UserProfileInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(PostModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Text")
    comment_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

## view:

```
def user_add_comment(request):
      post_pk = request.GET.get('post_pk', None)
      post = PostModel.objects.get(pk=post_pk)
      user_info = UserProfileInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
      user_info2 = UserProfileInfo()
      for temp_user_info in user_info:
         user_info2 = temp_user_info
      break
      comment_text = request.GET.get('post_text', None)
      comment = CommentPostModel(profile_user=user_info2, post=post, 
      text=comment_text)
      comment.save()
      data = {
      "url": "/profile_page",
      }
      return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: You are trying to use `user_info2` but it wasn't saved yet. You didn't call `user_info2.save()` . You have a strange `for` loop interacting with `user_info` and `user_info2` could you clarify why do you need it?

Comment: Why does you `Comment` model have a relationship to `UserProfileInfo` rather than directly to the `User` model? Then you wouldn't have to create an empty user profile when posting a comment. Also since you have a 1-to-1 relationship, `request.user.userprofileinfo` will return the associated profile if it exists (and raise `DoesNotExist` if not, so you would need to catch that). That way you don't have to do the `filter` thing.

Comment: The easiest way will be to use the User model with CommentPostModel with OneToOneField so that their will not be more conflicts and then this will also going to help you access userprofile efficiently rather then doing reverse relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't save user_info2 object. So change it like this:

```
for temp_user_info in user_info:
         user_info2 = temp_user_info
         user_info2.save()
```

## Edit

As your requirements, you can change your code like this

```
def user_add_comment(request):
      post_pk = request.GET.get('post_pk', None)
      post = PostModel.objects.get(pk=post_pk)
      user_info = UserProfileInfo.objects.get(user=request.user)
      comment_text = request.GET.get('post_text', None)
      comment = CommentPostModel(profile_user=user_info, post=post, 
                                 text=comment_text
                                )
      comment.save()
      data = {
      "url": "/profile_page",
      }
      return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: it's not the one inside the forloop that needs to be saved (it already is), it's if the loop doesn't have any elements that it needs to be saved.

Comment: I want to get a record that user field is this user. So i use filter and use for loop to get this record that is unique also. Do you have other idea? can i use (  user_info = UserProfileInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).first() ) ?

Comment: what do you mean by this user? is it 'logged in user'? do you want to implement comment system?